# flask, raspberry pi, pi-hole - connection refused

Tags: linux, networking, webserver

I'm trying my hand at some development.
I created a python flask ask that I am running on a raspberry pi (that is also running pi-hole).

I can reach the flask app locally with curl.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/
>Hello, World!pi@hole:~/piapi/app $
```

But I cannot reach it from another host on the network:

```
curl http://192.168.0.2:5000
>curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.2 port 5000: Connection refused
```

I assumed the port was blocked, but:

```
netstat -tupln | grep ':5000'
>tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30171/python3
```

That looks <strike>OK</strike> wrong to me~, and I can hit the pi-hole web app that runs on port 80.
What am I doing wrong? Why can't I reach the flask app on port 5000?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood how flask works.
I ran flask from the command line `flask run`, and that ignored the host settings in the python file. Running the app with:

`flask run --host=0.0.0.0`

See this post for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940807/290962